# Scrape HTML from websites which reloads page after few seconds

Tags: java, htmlunit

I want to scrape HTML from websites like http://www3.mangafreak.net/Manga/One_Piece using Jsoup and HtmlUnit. Problem with websites like this is first it give

> Status Code:503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

and then after few seconds it reloads the page with

> Status Code:200 OK

Comment: add a timeout ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis timeout for status code: 503 is 244ms and timeout for status code: 200 is 754ms

Comment: so in your code you cant add a timeout of a second before running your code?

Comment: Why do you need to scrape it more than once every few seconds?  They probably implemented this feature on their server to prevent stuff like this.

Comment: @EduardoDennis i tried with adding timeout in my code but it gave me html of status code: 503

Comment: can you provide examples of your code ?

Comment: @SteveSmith so can't I scrape html from website like this?

Comment: What is the idea of using Jsoup and HtmlUnit together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (HtmlUnit only)

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("http://www3.mangafreak.net/Manga/One_Piece");
    System.out.println(page.asXml());

    WebWindow window = page.getEnclosingWindow();
    window.getJobManager().waitForJobsStartingBefore(5000);

    page = (HtmlPage) window.getEnclosedPage();
    System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

No you have the page and you can use the HtmlUnit API for having fun with the DOM tree or to click on something....

Comment: This is what I am looking for.